# Is it possible to build a custom split view as Salesforce has done with High Velocity Sales?

Tags: lightning-web-components, console

I'd like to customize the split view panel in the console view as Salesforce has done with the high velocity sales console view, using LWC components.

[image: Salesforce High Velocity Sales Custom Split View]

How do they support the tabular navigation of the console view while having a custom split view ?

Comment: Have you considered using the browser's DOM and source navigators (available through the debugger/inspector depending on the browser) to get an idea as to how the page is structured and where parts of that structure originates from standard/specific LWC or Aura components?

Comment: If you want to customize the split view (so it's not just a list view), then I'd presume you'd have to build it yourself - you can see split view in [slds here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/split-view/). Can probably use `lightning-layout` to divide your page up the way you'd like or change depending on opening/closing of the split view.

Comment: you can also create custom Template for the page and use it to do similar behaviour as a Split View